# Adding Jar To Ant Build

Tags: java, ant, build, travis-ci

I try to add json jar to my Travis-CI ant build, I also checked questions in stackoverflow this question is might be duplicate but I cant handle with it. When travis compiles my code it can not JSON, I think I do something wrong in build xml. Please help me, I m new at Ant.

```
  <project name="Hello" basedir="." default="main">
       <property name="dir.src"     value="src"/>
       <property name="dir.build"   value="build"/>
       <property name="dir.classes" value="${dir.build}/classes"/>
       <property name="dir.jar"     value="${dir.build}/jar"/>

       <property name="main-class"  value="TestConsole"/>
       <target name="clean">
           <delete dir="${dir.build}"/>
       </target>

       <target name="compile">
           <mkdir dir="${dir.classes}"/>
            <javac srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.classes}"/>
       </target>

           <target name="jar" depends="clean, compile">
              <mkdir dir="${build}/${jar}" />
              <jar destfile="src/json-simple-1.1.1.jar" basedir="${build}/${classes}">
               <manifest>
                   <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MainClass" />
               </manifest>
              </jar>
       </target>

       <target name="run" depends="jar">
           <java jar="${dir.jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
       </target>

       <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
       <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
  </project>
```

Comment: Can you show exact error when build fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
<project name="Hello" basedir="." default="main">
<property name="dir.src"     value="src"/>
<property name="dir.build"   value="build"/>
<property name="dir.classes" value="${dir.build}/classes"/>
<property name="dir.jar"     value="${dir.build}/jar"/>
<property name="dir.lib"     value="."/>
<property name="main-class"  value="TestConsole"/>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${dir.build}"/>
</target>

 //Edited part

<target name="compile">
<mkdir dir="${dir.classes}"/>
<javac srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.classes}">
    <classpath>
           <fileset dir="${dir.lib}">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
           </fileset>
     </classpath>
  </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<mkdir dir="${dir.jar}"/>
<jar destfile="${dir.jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${dir.classes}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
    </manifest>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${dir.lib}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</jar>

//Edited part ends here

</target>
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${dir.jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because java compiler is not able to find required classes for compilation. You need to make available all required jars to `javac` by means of class-path.

So in your build xml you need to specify class path like this:

```
  <path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="bin/"/> <!-- to put a folder in class path -->
    <pathelement location="lib/helper.jar"/> <!-- to put a jar in class path -->
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>
  </path>
```

And then use this class path while executing `javac` like this:

```
<javac srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.classes}">
     <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
</javac>
```

Similarly you have to do it while running your class using `java`

Please see [writing a simple build file](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your help btw I find a solution without using path id.

Comment: Please add that as an answer so that it can help someone else in same situation. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this example which covers how to share dependencies found in `classpath.test` (such as gson) **across different ant commands** which will make the CI pass with this build.xml on `ant test` command too!

```
<project name="junit-example">
  <property name="main.build.dir" value="build/main"/>
  <property name="main.src.dir" value="src/package"/>
  <property name="test.build.dir" value="build/test"/>
  <property name="test.src.dir" value="tests/package"/>

  <path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/gson-2.8.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${main.build.dir}"/>
  </path>

  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${main.build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${main.src.dir}" destdir="${main.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${test.build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="classpath.test"/>
          <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${test.build.dir}" includes="**/*Test*" />
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
  </target>
</project>
```